# shared_ptr compiler error invalid conversion

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, nfa

I have a class called `State` which has a `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and a `int` as its fields. I also have another class called `Automata` which has a `shared_ptr` to a state. I am using `State` to mimic a state in NFA. The `Automata` is a linked list of states in an NFA. And states are linked with `shared_ptr`, self loop is indicated by `weak_ptr`.

```
class State {
    public:
        // ptr to next state
        std::shared_ptr<State> nextState;
        // ptr to self
        std::weak_ptr<State> selfLoop;
        // char
        int regex;
       // Constructor
       State(const int c) : regex(c){}
       // Destructor
       ~State();
};
#define START 256

#define FINAL 257

class Automata {
    private:
       std::shared_ptr<State> start;
    public:
       // Constructor, string should not be empty
       Automata(const std::string &str);
      // Destructor
      ~Automata();
      // Determine a string matched regex
      bool match(const std::string &str);
};
```

The constructor of `Automata` basically takes in a regex and convert it into an NFA.(It works! See this if you are interested: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

The compiler error happens when compiling `Automata`'s constructor. It is implemented as follows

```
Automata::Automata(const string &str) {
    start = make_shared<State>(new State(START)); // Error is here, START defined above
    for (loop traversing str) {
        //add more states to start
    }
}
```

I got an error that states

```
// A lot gibbrish above
Automata.cc:7:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: invalid conversion
from ‘State*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
^
 In file included from Automata.h:4:0,
                  from Automata.cc:2:
 State.h:18:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘State::State(int)’ [-fpermissive]
 State(const int c);
 ^
```

Not sure what I did wrong. I am totally new to `shared_ptr`, so I have no idea if it's the problem of `make_shared` or error with `State` constructor? Can you help me fix this?

Comment: When using `make_shared` you should not use new. `make_shared` perfect forwards its arguments on to the `State` constructor and this is where your error occurs (it forwards a `State` pointer and its expecting an int). You should just use the same arguments as you would when constructing a `State` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you want to write:

```
Automata::Automata(const string &str) {
    start = make_shared<State>(START); // make_shared will call new internally
    for (loop traversing str) {
        //add more states to start
    }
}
```

?